# How to manage content dimension?

Tags: css

I need to create a circle with an image inside, so far I almost achieved this but I want set the `content` dimension too, this is my code:

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: -25%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #a7151f;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #a7151f;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: url("logo");
}
```

```html
<img class="img-responsive center-block circle">
```

this is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c306bavx/).

As you can see I have to display only half of the circle, but the problem is that the logo is not entire visible. How can I manage this?

Comment: I assume the `top: -25%` is your problem, but I'm not certain what you're asking.

Comment: @DBS I need the `top -25%` 'cause I have to display only half of the circle, I just need to display the logo in the circle correctly without missing part

Comment: If you need a half-circle with the logo positioned in a specific location, I would use a `div` with a background image, and use background positioning. The `img` element isn't particularly flexible with how the image is displayed.

Comment: could you please show me an example?

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mre] in the question itself. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I added the code in the question and the fiddle too, not sure why you said that

Comment: Not sure how this shows a circle with an image inside when there is no image source...

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh sorry I forgot to add the image source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you needed to give the img a z-index greater than the circles and then center it ontop of the circle.

Here's the code:

```css
.circle{
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      top: -250px;
      left: 50%;
      border: 5px solid #a7151f;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      line-height: 0;
      text-align:center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      background-color: #a7151f;
      width: 500px;
      height: 400px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      }
     .img {
       content: url("https://www.google.it/logos/doodles/2019/rugby-world-cup-2019-opening-day-6753651837108235-l.png");
       z-index: 10;
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       transform : translateX(-50%);
     }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>
<div class="img">
</div>
```

here is the jsfiddle fix: http://jsfiddle.net/t5L49f7g/

Hope this helps!

Comment: In this way the circle is full displayed.. I need to display the circle at the top and only half of it

Comment: Check the new answer I fixed it in the fiddle :)

Comment: @Ameer you should use `top: -250px` instead of `top: -50%` to make sure it will work on each windowheight. :)